# Removing yourself from Visual Studio Team Services Accounts

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

On my visualstudio.com dashboard it says I am a member to a Team Service Account. How can I remove myself? The project is long done and I don't want to see that anymore. I am not the owner and cannot contact him.

Comment: What dashboard like (says I am a member to a Team Service Account), you can provide the screenshot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is now available in VSTS (now Azure DevOps Services). Login to one of your VSTS Account go to "My Profile". (top right corner) Then you can leave VSTS Accounts where your Account is a member.

[Azure DevOps Services - leaving your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-leave-organization?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 4):

No, only account owner or administrator (in Project Collection Administrators group, Admin page > Security > Project Collection Administrators) can add or delete the account.

Comment: @crystyxn - answer by Maik below should be marked as correct - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688264/2365197